# iTerm2, unicode and sympy

Tags: terminal, iterm, python, macos

In my both Mac (OS X Mavericks) and Ubuntu machine, I have installed sympy that is a python library for symbolic mathematics. Part of `sympy` is the pretty print functionality that uses unicode characters to prettify symbolic expressions in the command-line environments with unicode support. For example, in my Ubuntu machine and in its `gnome-terminal` running the following code

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol("x")
pprint(Integral(sqrt(1/x), x))
```

renders to

[image]

However, the same command in OS X with iTerm2 (that should support unicode) results in

[image]

I'm using `sympy 0.7.5` that I have made from source with the latest build of `iTerm2` (Build 1.0.0.20140518). Is there anything that I miss here? [The lead developer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/6446/asmeurer) of sympy is one of the StackExchange network. It would be great to know his opinion on this one.

Comment: At this moment running your example through [live.sympy.org](http://live.sympy.org) throws a lot of unicode errors - maybe there is a general issue with the most recent build?

Comment: @Asmus what do you mean Unicode errors? If it doesn't render correctly, that is an issue with your browser or the font that it is using.

Comment: @asmeurer I tried copy&pasting the above three python lines directly into the browser session (Safari) and had the following output: `Exception in SymPy Live of type 
<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>`
[. . . ]
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2320' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`. I can send you the whole error output if you like.

Comment: @Asmus if you could open an [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy-live/issues/new) for it that would be great. I can't reproduce it myself.

Comment: @asmeurer The issue can now be [found here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy-live/issues/87)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found out what the problem is. The problem was *not* with the terminal emulators themselves as both `OSX Terminal` and `iTerm2` were using `UTF-8` by default. It turned out one has to inform python explicitly that the terminal is capable of handling unicode by way of

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9930894/811098) stackoverflow answer.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of this environment variable. I wonder if this is a situation that is handled better by Python 3.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Even tried Python 3 in the hopes that it might just work, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your terminal in the iTerm preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal supports Unicode (the character encoding should be "Unicode (UTF-8)". SymPy will choose ASCII if the terminal does not report that it supports Unicode.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm afraid that is not the problem. In both iTerm2 and Terminal I have `UTF-8` as character encoding and yet it's not working.